# How do I stop app in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, terminate

I must be missing something totally obvious, but I can't find a simple way to simply stop an app from running. I'm running it on my HTC One.

I first tried toggling the green run arrow. Didn't work.
I found a "Terminate Application" circle in the lower left of the window. That doesn't seem to do anything when you click it. It seems to be grayed out, non-functional. Screen shot here
http://www.screencast.com/t/VLTOzPQ7

So, I closed the entire project. That worked, but also the entire Android Studio closed instantly. Then reopening Android Studio failed (stack dump). Then reopening again worked, but it took 30 minutes to load my project.

To stop the next time, I turned my phone off, then closed the project. That seems to have worked better, since it took me to the Welcome to Android Studio screen and invited me to open or start a project.

Maybe there's an easier way to stop an app? I see the same question on this forum but no solutions.

Answer (score 3):

The Android Studio controls you are trying to use only work if you are running your app in the emulator. There are a few ways to do this when you are using an actual device or VM (e.g., Genymotion):

1. Use the UI of the phone to `Force Stop` the application. This is done in the `Settings->Apps` menu.
2. Use Android Studio's terminal window or the host's shell and issue the command:

   `adb shell am force-stop <package-name>`
3. Open Android Device Monitor (green "Droid" icon), select the process under the `Devices` tab and click the `Stop Process` button (stop sign icon). This is basically the GUI way of doing #2.

Answer (score 1):

You need to select the process you want to terminate (ex. com.myname.myapp) then click terminate application.

Answer (score 0):

Since the application is running on your phone, you need to end the application process on the phone. When you do that the application would be shown as terminated on Android Studio.